# Pattern matching in system path using C++ functionalities

Tags: c++, regex, qt, environment-variables

I am working on Installation of particular Qt based Windows GUI application, which needs DLLs to be placed in the `PATH` system environment variable. For placing I could somehow manage to append `Installation_path` to `PATH`. But while uninstallation of my application I want to search for where my installation path is and then I've to remove those and put normal path as usually without modifying it. Is a regex my companion or any other way in doing this?

P.S. I cannot use `boost` lib.

Comment: You should test at least 4 cases: the common case where it's somewhere in the middle of PATH, but also when your dir is the first, last, or only component of PATH.

Comment: Right Mr.Salters, I've to search the whole path for suppose: `C:\Application_Name\libs\dll_directory_1`; `C:\Application_Name\libs\dll_directory_2`; `C:\Application_Name\libs\dll_directory_3`. I need to search my `Application_name` and return all the above paths (3 or more) and then remove them..

Comment: Well, you're supposed to put them in `\Program files\` or its localized variant (see `FOLDERID_ProgramFiles`). You should store your install paths in the registry, and search for those exact paths at uninstall time. But why use so many DLL directories?

Comment: Well I am not registering them, just putting them in the System Path. I presume I've to use `vector` to push_back all the paths with delimiter `;` and then read one by one by using `[]` or `at()` operators and find or search them. Well so many DLL's are required as this app uses different modules of different platforms

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regex, all you need to do is locate a substring, case-insensitive. Since you have Qt, use [`indexOf`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#indexOf)